# SQLAlchemy Table Creation case-insensitive Columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a SQLAlchemy table with a certain column that is case-insensitive. I have read Dologan's solution from [Case insensitive string columns in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680140/case-insensitive-string-columns-in-sqlalchemy) . But considering the updates that have gone on from versions (my version currently is 1.0.11) I was hoping that there might be a built in argument to render entries as case insensitive.

```
class Bob(Base, ...):
    __tablename__ = "Alice"
    steve = Column(String, nullable=False, *case-insensitive parameter*?)
```

Comment: There is, and it is explained in an answer to the question you linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31599335/2681632

Comment: @IljaEverilä Understood. I also did not realize that not only do I need to restart the application I am using it for after applying the 'collation' change, but I need to drop the table as well and restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst not a direct answer may be a workaround.. (the below allows you to write to `steve` but it saves into `_steve` formatted to lowercase)

```
class Bob(Base, ...):
    __tablename__ = "Alice"
    _steve = Column(String, nullable=False)

    @property . # hybrid_property for search queries?
    def steve(self):
        return self._steve

    @steve.setter
    def steve(self, value):
        self._steve = value.lower()
```

You can query based on lowercase:

```
Bob.query.filter(Bob._steve == 'SomE TexT'.lower())
```

This might also work depending on some other properties I think explained in SQLalchemy docs as `hybrid_properties`:

```
Bob.query.filter(Bob.steve == 'SomE TexT'.lower())
```